# Why this PHP PDO Mysql code not working?

Tags: php

I used Like operator and pass all the parameter But Still the following code is  not working:

```
public function get_locations($lang, $suggest){
        $this->lang = $lang;
        $this->suggest = $suggest;
        $sql = "SELECT l.location_id, l.location_name_col 
                FROM test_db.location_translations as l
                WHERE l.location_name_col like LIKE :suggest
                AND   l.language_code = :lang
                ";

         $params = array(':suggest'=>"%".$this->suggest."%", ':lang'=> $this->lang);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);            
        $stmt->execute($params);
    }
```

I am getting the following erros:

> PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'LIKE '%A%'
>                   AND   l.language_code = 'en'' at line 3

please help me.

Comment: any error you are getting? CHANGE LIKE `':suggest'=>"%".$this->suggest`  Or  `':suggest'=>"%".$this->suggest."%"`

Comment: What's not working? Not working how? Is it just not finding all of the hits you expect? In that case, you probably need to add a second `%` placeholder, as in `$params = array(':suggest'=>"%" . $this->suggest . "%", ':lang'=> $this->lang);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looking at your error code the problem has to do with the 'LIKE' parameter, I see that you are using 'like' and 'LIKE'. I think it should look like this:

> $sql = "SELECT l.location_id, l.location_name_col FROM
>   test_db.location_translations as l WHERE l.location_name_col LIKE
>   :suggest AND l.language_code = :lang ";

What if you run it again with the above code, what happens then?